# Prove that $f^{(k)}(0) = \frac{k!}{2πi} \int_{|z|=1} \frac{f(z)}{z^{k+1}} dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, power-series

Let $f(z)$ be a convergent power series with convergent radius greater than 1. Prove that $$f^{(k)}(0) = \frac{k!}{2πi} \int_{|z|=1} \frac{f(z)}{z^{k+1}} dz$$

Since $f(z)$ is a convergent power series, $f(z) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} z^n \implies \int_{|z|=1} f(z) = \int_{|z|=1} \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} z^n$

Since $\int_{|z|=1} z^n = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ne -1}$ by the Closed Curve Theorem, and $\int_{|z|=1} z^{-1} = 2\pi i$

$\int_{|z|=1} f(z) = \int_{|z|=1} \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} z^n \implies \int_{|z|=1} f(z) = \int_{|z|=1} \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} z^{-1} = \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} \int_{|z|=1} z^{-1} = \frac{2\pi if^{(k)}(0)}{k!}$

So $\int_{|z|=1} f(z) = \frac{2\pi if^{(k)}(0)}{k!} \implies f^{(k)}(0) = \frac{k!}{2πi} \int_{|z|=1} f(z) dz $

I know I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note if $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(k)}(0)z^k}{k!}$, then

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{|z|=1}f(z)\,dz&=\oint_{|z|=1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(k)}(0)z^k}{k!}\,dz\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}\oint_{|z|=1}z^k\,dz\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

since $\oint_{|z|=1}z^n\,dz=0$ for all $n\ne -1$ (as written in the OP).

However, we have

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{f(z)}{z^{k+1}}\,dz&=\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)z^n}{n!}}{z^{k+1}}\,dz\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\oint_{|z|=1}z^{n-k-1}\,dz\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\left(2\pi i\delta_{n,k}\right)\\\\
&=2\pi i\,\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}
\end{align}$$

for $k\ge 0$.  Solving for $f^{(k)}(0)$ yields

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{f^{(k)}(0)=\frac{k!}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{f(z)}{z^{k+1}}\,dz}$$

as was to be shown!